# FFMPEG cuts off audio at end of clips

Tags: ffmpeg

When I run this command

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/controlroom/Documents/Recording/FPR/BASH/fpr.mp3 \
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:25:00 -c copy \
/Users/controlroom/Documents/Recording/FPR/FINALS/`date -j -v+0d -f "%Y_%m_%d" "$date_input" +%m-%d-%y`/National_M-F/`date -j -v+0d -f "%Y_%m_%d" "$date_input" +%m_%d_%Y`_FPR_25Min_PGM.mp3; #Monday
```

It cuts the audio off from an mp3 file at the end of the file it creates.

Strangely, the file is 25 minutes long (cut from a much longer mp3 file), so the physical length is correct, but the audio cut off from the mp3 is not.

Running the same command with a .wav file does not cut off audio at the end. FFMPEG is only having problems with the mp3 file. FFMPEG is also giving me this error:

> [mp3 @ 0x7fd73b80d000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate.

So I think it's estimating the length of the mp3 file incorrectly, but this same error message does not appear for .wav files.

I tried several other commands to no avail.

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/controlroom/Documents/Recording/FPR/BASH/fpr.mp3 \
-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:25:00 -c copy \
/Users/controlroom/Documents/Recording/FPR/FINALS/`date -j -v+0d -f "%Y_%m_%d" "$date_input" +%m-%d-%y`/National_M-F/`date -j -v+0d -f "%Y_%m_%d" "$date_input" +%m_%d_%Y`_FPR_25Min_PGM.mp3; #Monday
```